# Fixed width import with field-widths depending on first char of line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, fixed-width

I need to import a file of this kind of format:

```
PParent line     has some fields            with fixed width
CChild line of Parent     Has fixed width with different widths than Parent
CAnother Child            Fixed width consistent with Child-lines but not Parent
PSecond Parent   has more fields            again fixed width like other Parents
CThird Child              This time belong to 2nd Parent as that's the preceding P-line
```

So the widths with which the columns are fixed are dependent on the first character being P vs. C. I did not come up with this file format, but I'm the sucker that needs to deal with it... I'm currently reading it like so (simplified):

```
create table #fixed (
    line varchar(max)
)
create table #link (
    id int identity,
    parent int,
    linetype char,
    line varchar(max)
)

bulk insert #fixed from '\\unc\path\to\file.txt'
with (
    fieldterminator = ''
)

insert into #link(linetype, line)
select substring(line, 1, 1), line
from #fixed

update c set
    c.parent = p.id
from #link c
cross apply (
    select top 1 id from #link
    where linetype = 'P' and id < c.id
    order by id desc
) p
where c.linetype = 'C'
```

This works, but I don't like it in general and I'm particularly concerned about SQL Server inserting into `#link` with arbitrary order, thereby losing the correct Parent-Child relations in the `update`, particularly for larger files than just these 5 lines.

But I don't see a way to enforce an `order` here, or import this fixed-width-with-varying-widths format with a `bulk insert` that uses a format-file.

***Edit:*** One way I see is to read the file with `openrowset(bulk '\\unc\file.txt', single_clob)` and manually extract the lines. Mainly my question now is, should I be worried enough about this order of the `insert into #link` that warrants switching to reading as a `single_clob`?

Comment: Are you able to make use of a technology like SSIS?  You would be able to read in your flat file and assign a sequential row number to each line as it was read in.

Comment: I'm restricted to doing this is a piece of T-SQL that can be stored and run when the file is detected in a folder by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial approach is likely to hit problems because

```
insert into #link(linetype, line)
select substring(line, 1, 1), line
from #fixed
```

has no `ORDER BY` clause; there's no guarantee that the order the rows would be inserted into `#link` would reflect their order in the source file.

One approach would be to add an identity column to `#fixed`:

```
CREATE TABLE #fixed (
    id INT IDENTITY,
    line VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

since `BULK INSERT` will add the rows to the target table in the order they appear in the source file.

This means that you'll need to use a format file to enable `BULK INSERT` to skip the `IDENTITY` column.

The format file would need to have contents something like:

```
9.0
1
1 SQLCHAR 0 99999 "\r\n" 2  line  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

It can then be used with a command like

```
BULK INSERT #fixed FROM '\\unc\path\to\file.txt'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '',
    FORMATFILE  = 'c:\temp\test.fmt'
)
```

(assuming you've saved the format file to c:\temp\test.fmt)

You could then use the code you already have with a minor modification to use the id from `#fixed`:

```
create table #link (
    id int ,
    parent int,
    linetype char,
    line varchar(max)
)

insert into #link(id, linetype, line)
select id, substring(line, 1, 1), line
from #fixed
order by id
```

Comment: Ah, I can have the format-file tell `bulk insert` to skip columns, brilliant! I actually tweaked your format file to have it insert directly into `#link` and skip both `id` and `parent`. This way I get my `linetype` value immediately too. Thanks so much.